# Wilcoxon rank sum test paired data in R and SAS

Tags: r, sas

I want to compare data between two period (1 and 2) for paired data.
I used wilcoxon rank sum test, but I obtain two different results from R, one of this equal to SAS.

Which one is the correct one for my data?

```
   wilcox.test(val ~ time, data = pcs, paired = TRUE)


        Wilcoxon signed rank test

    data:  val by time
    V = 9, p-value = 0.4688
    alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

    > pcs$val<-as.numeric(pcs$val)
    > pcs$time<-as.numeric(pcs$time)
    > wilcox.test(pcs$time,pcs$val, paired = TRUE)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test

    data:  pcs$time and pcs$val
    V = 50, p-value = 0.9032
    alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

    La procedura UNIVARIATE
    Variabile: pcs

    Moments 
N 7 Sum Weights 7 
Mean 10.5371745 Sum Observations 73.7602214 
Std Deviation 32.3329768 Variance 1045.42139 
Skewness -0.2374077 Kurtosis -0.6500825 
Uncorrected SS 7049.75266 Corrected SS 6272.52833 
Coeff Variation 306.846744 Std Error Mean 12.2207165 



Basic Statistical Measures 
Location Variability 
Mean 10.53717 Std Deviation 32.33298 
Median 7.58871 Variance 1045 
Mode . Range 93.59909 
    Interquartile Range 56.97430 



Tests for Location: Mu0=0 
Test Statistic p Value 
Student's t t 0.862239 Pr > |t| 0.4217 
Sign M 1.5 Pr >= |M| 0.4531 
Signed Rank S 5 Pr >= |S| 0.4688 



Quantiles (Definition 5) 
Level Quantile 
100% Max 55.37457 
99% 55.37457 
95% 55.37457 
90% 55.37457 
75% Q3 36.56551 
50% Median 7.58871 
25% Q1 -20.40879 
10% -38.22452 
5% -38.22452 
1% -38.22452 
0% Min -38.22452 



Extreme Observations 
Lowest Highest 
Value Obs Value Obs 
-38.22452 5 7.18289 6 
-20.40879 1 7.58871 7 
7.18289 6 25.68185 4 
7.58871 7 36.56551 2 
25.68185 4 55.37457 3
```

I usually use SAS, but a p-value of 0.4688 looked so strange to me looking at this plot:

[image]

So I tried on R, but I don't obtain a significant difference, so I don't understand...

Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you want to compare time vs val, or for two different time periods the val data ?

Comment: It depends on your experimental question. The syntax you are using will determine what you are testing. `wilcox.test(val, time)` means test `val` against `time`, as two independent samples. `wilcox.test(val ~ time)` tests `val` with time as a grouping variable, which looks like it'll test `val` in `EX` against `val` in `EX+D`. Are `pcs` and `mcs` another group? Google tells me those are physical health, and mental health scores, which I'd think aren't independent of patient.

Comment: I don't think that plot is going to tell you much, just displaying % difference. Plot them as `boxplots`, summarize the data and examine it, Q-Q plots, etc., then test.

Comment: Thak you! I want to test `val` in `EX` against `val` in` EX+D`. `val` is for value, EX and EX+D are my two times. I would like to understand which time have the better values. So i think I sould use `wilcox.test(val ~ time)`. I would lie to know this for pcs and for mcs separately.